# Arduino Leonardo - disabling the debugger port

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo, keyboard

My Sketch program is working perfectly as a specialized keyboard application on the Leonardo. I want to disable the development tools drivers from the USB, (COM PORT) leaving only the HID Keyboard drivers.  I understand I will need to use the Arduino ISP or other method to load my code.

Is there any way to disable the drivers for the development tools from the on board USB, leaving just the HID drivers?

Comment: Other than modifying the core? (Which, BTW, doesn't affect the bootloader)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It would affect your ability to (easily) get into the bootloader since that relies on opening the (now non-existent) serial port at 1200 baud to trigger a reboot.

Comment: Never could get that to work. I just use Sparkfun's bootloader, which uses a double-press of the reset button to put it in programming mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way, no. You have to reprogram the core to break the connection between the USB interface and the CDC/ACM driver. That means working out a new set of descriptors, deleting chunks of code, patching around the newly created holes, etc.

Comment: I was afraid of that...

Comment: Is this driver code publicly available somewhere?

Comment: It is on your computer.